# Which of Ruby's concurrency devices would be best suited for this scenario?

Tags: ruby

The whole threads/fibers/processes thing is confusing me a little. I have a practical problem that can be solved with some concurrency, so I thought this was a good opportunity to ask professionals and people more knowledgable than me about it.

I have a long array, let's say 3,000 items. I want to send a HTTP request for each item in the array.

Actually iterating over the array, generating requests, and sending them is very rapid. What takes time is waiting for each item to be received, processed, and acknowledged by the party I'm sending to. I'm essentially sending 100 bytes, waiting 2 seconds, sending 100 bytes, waiting 2 seconds.

What I would like to do instead is send these requests asynchronously. I want to send a request, specify what to do when I get the response, and in the meantime, send the next request.

From what I can see, there are four concurrency options I could use here.

1. Threads.
2. Fibers.
3. Processes; unsuitable as far as I know because multiple processes accessing the same array isn't feasible/safe.
4. Asynchronous functionality like JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest`.

The simplest would seem to be the last one. But what is the best, simplest way to do that using Ruby?

Failing #4, which of the remaining three is the most sensible choice here?

Would any of these options also allow me to say "Have no more than 10 pending requests at any time"?

Comment: This question is not pragmatic enough for Stack Overflow. However, design questions like this one are probably a good fit for Programmers SE. You might want to flag your own post for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your classic producer/consumer problem and is nicely suited for threads in Ruby. Just create a Queue

```
urls = [...] # array with bunches of urls
require "thread"

queue = SizedQueue.new(10) # this will only allow 10 items on the queue at once

p1 = Thread.new do 
  url_slice = urls.each do |url|
    response = do_http_request(url)
    queue << response
  end
  queue << "done"
end

consumer = Thread.new do
  http_response = queue.pop(true) # don't block when zero items are in queue
  Thread.exit if http_response == "done"
  process(http_response)
end
# wait for the consumer to finish
consumer.join
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works really well and it's something new to me, quite interesting. My question is this: when I implemented it as you described, I put a loop in the consumer that continuously pops items from the queue, and then used multiple parallel consumers. Is that what I'm supposed to be doing? It makes the most sense, since the operation the consumer does each time is blocking... but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

EventMachine as an event loop and em-synchrony as a Fiber wrapper for it's callbacks into synchronous code

Copy Paste from [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) README

```
require "em-synchrony"
require "em-synchrony/em-http"
require "em-synchrony/fiber_iterator"

EM.synchrony do
  concurrency = 2
  urls = ['http://url.1.com', 'http://url2.com']
  results = []

  EM::Synchrony::FiberIterator.new(urls, concurrency).each do |url|
    resp = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    results.push resp.response
  end

  p results # all completed requests
  EventMachine.stop
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an IO bounded case that fits more in both:

- Threading model: no problem with MRI Ruby in this case cause threads work well with IO cases; GIL effect is almost zero.
- Asynchronous model, which proves(in practice and theory) to be far superior than threads when it comes to IO specific problems.

For this specific case and to make things far simpler, I would have gone with [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) HTTP client which has a [parallel](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests) support that works as the evented(Asynchronous) concurrency model.

Example:

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
%w(url1 url2 url3).each do |url|
  request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, followlocation: true)
  request.on_complete do |response|
    # do something with response
  end
  hydra.queue(request)
end
hydra.run # this is a blocking call that returns once all requests are complete
```